# How to display the missing output message while execute sudo service/systemctl on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, systemd, output, sysv

We already knew that from Ubuntu 15 and above are using `systemd`, however the famous and unbeatable `SysV` still supported.

But there is a small issue which annoying (me and whom may concern). I love the way `SysV` display output while I executed `sudo service [name] restart|start|...`.

Is there any posiblities to bring it back? Like the old time we had with 14.04?

## UPDATED

For example,

In 14.04, when I execute this command:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

I will get an "output" message like this:

```
ssh stop/waiting
ssh start/running, process 83054
```

Regards.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Operating system display output"?

Comment: @Jos: I updated the question, please check.

Comment: No, the `systemd` equivalent `systemctl start ssh` outputs nothing, and there is no `--verbose` option. There is only `systemctl status ssh` and `journalctl --unit=ssh`.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to write your own alias functions to do it. Simple alias woun't work because you need to get arguments from command line. That's why I wrote a functions with strange names, so they do not collapse with existing ones.

Here are mine `~/.aliases` that are loaded in shell profile.

```
alias stop='__stp() { sudo systemctl stop "$1" && sudo systemctl status "$1" -n 2; }; __stp'
alias start='__str() { sudo systemctl start "$1" && sudo systemctl status "$1" -n 2; }; __str'
alias restart='__rst() { sudo systemctl restart "$1" && sudo systemctl status "$1" -n 2; }; __rst'
alias reload='__rld() { sudo systemctl reload "$1" && sudo systemctl status "$1" -n 2; }; __rld'
alias enable='__ebl() { sudo systemctl enable "$1" && sudo systemctl status "$1" -n 2; }; __ebl'
alias status='sudo systemctl status'
```

Then just run:

```
restart ssh
```

It outputs the next command `systemctl status` with additional argument `-n 2` to show only last 2 lines from `journal` log file.